# Server Behaviours grayed out in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: dreamweaver

Not sure if this is the right place, but lately I've been following this tutorial (word for word almost) and i get to this part where i am supposed to add a server behavior recordset, except this is grayed out. Does anyone know how to fix this. My connection is valid (to the server) and everything seem to be working fine :c

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial I was following was based on CS5 and I've never used it before. I went to Bindings and added a recordset there. Works exactly the same.